# How to implement multiline text inside fixedSize() VStack?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I Want to create bubble chat like whatsapp where the bubble will shrink based on its content. I try several solution but none of them worked. Note: Beside text, there will always be some content with .infinity width (ie. divider)

1.

[short text is okay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBgMT.png)
[long text sholdnt be truncated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHwqS.png)

```
            VStack {
                Text("I Want to create bubble chat like whatsapp where the bubble will shrink based on its content.")
                Divider()
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    TimeChatOverlay(Date())
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: 280)
            .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
            .background(Color.red.opacity(0.1))
```

2. 

[short text is okay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBgMT.png)
[background size is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5acZx.png)

```
            VStack {
                Text("I Want to create bubble chat like whatsapp where the bubble will shrink based on its content.")
                    .frame(maxWidth: 280)
                Divider()
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    TimeChatOverlay(Date())
                }
            }
            .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
            .background(Color.red.opacity(0.1))
```

What i see is, the problem comes from Text() that will always be truncated if using fixedSize modifier.

I hope somebody could help me, thank you

Multiline text inside fixed size container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for those who have similar problem, the only solution that i found is by using `UILabel` instead of swiftUI Text. It seems that text in swiftUI will always be truncated if the parent container contain `fixedSize()` modifier, there is no way you can modified `fixedSize` in its child view. Here is the code:

```
private struct Label: UIViewRepresentable {
let text: String?
let font: UIFont?
let textAlignment: NSTextAlignment?
let textColor: UIColor?
let preferredMaxLayoutWidth: CGFloat

@Environment(\.lineLimit) private var lineLimit: Int?

init(
    _ text: String?,
    font: UIFont? = nil,
    textAlignment: NSTextAlignment? = nil,
    textColor: UIColor? = nil,
    preferredMaxLayoutWidth: CGFloat
) {
    self.text = text
    self.font = font
    self.textAlignment = textAlignment
    self.textColor = textColor
    self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = preferredMaxLayoutWidth
}

func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Label>) -> UILabel {
    let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
    
    label.numberOfLines = lineLimit ?? 0
    if let textColor = textColor {
        label.textColor = textColor
    }
    if let font = font {
        label.font = font
    }
    label.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
    label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
    label.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
    label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
    label.allowsDefaultTighteningForTruncation = true
    label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.8
    
    updateUIView(label, context: context)
    return label
}

func updateUIView(_ label: UILabel, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Label>) {
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = textAlignment ?? .natural
    label.text = text
    label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = preferredMaxLayoutWidth
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a quick play around. Does this help?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            Text("I Want to create bubble chat like whatsapp where the bubble will shrink based on its content. ")
            Divider()
            Text("\(Date().description)")
                .font(.footnote)

        }
        .padding(10)
        .background(Color.red.opacity(0.1))
        .frame(maxWidth: 280)
        .cornerRadius(15)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it will not shrinking if the text is short. Thats why im using .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false) in vstack